# Change a formula field and get Data Uniqueness Violation - The proposed data changes would violate a uniqueness constraint

Tags: formula-field, platform-encryption, shield-encryption

**Given**

- Existing custom field `Asset.SerialNumber` (OOTB - Text)
- New custom field `Asset.SerialNumber_bis__c` (*Text255, External Id non-unique, deterministic encrypted case insensitive*)
- Existing custom *formula* field `Case.SerialNumber__c` that is defined as `Asset__r.SerialNumber`

**When**

- use UI field Editor and change the formula in `Case.SerialNumber__c`
- FROM: `Asset__r.SerialNumber`
- TO: `Asset__r.SerialNumber_bis__c`

**RESULT**

> `Data Uniqueness Violation - The proposed data changes would violate a uniqueness constraint.` upon attempting to save the changed formula field

How do I get around this problem? The newly-referenced field isn't defined to be unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I have no idea why this is happening but this is the **workaround**:

On the object with the formula field ...

- Define a new field to be exactly what you were trying to change the old field to. In my situation, that meant defining a new field on Case:

  `Case.SerialNumber_bis__c` with formula expression `Asset__r.SerialNumber_bis__c`
- Save the new field
- Hide the old field, perhaps also changing its label
- If you are lucky enough (no Apex/VF references), you might be able to delete the original field, and rename the new field (label and api name) back to the original field's name. This will deploy successfully with Metadata API-based tools.

**Notes**

- An option you might try - Changing the encryption method on `Asset.SerialNumber_bis__c` does not work because External Ids must be deterministically-encrypted
- Another option you might try is to remove the External Id from `Asset.SerialNumber_bis__c` but then you lose the index and your queries won't be selective. Asking for a custom index is a no-go because SFDC can't create custom indices on encrypted text fields - Catch-22!
- A final option you might try is to directly encrypt `Asset.SerialNumber`. Ooops - doesn't work because this OOTB field is not encryptable!

Comment: If you use case-sensitive deterministic encryption we do support custom indexes.  We do not for case-insensitive, though.  Details on indexing support (and other considerations) when using deterministic encryption can be found here: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=security_pe_deterministic_considerations.htm&type=5

Comment: @JohnWhelan - true - but workaround or call to Support for custom index shouldn't be required here to change a formula ref from an unencrypted field to an encrypted field

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem.
Here is what helped:
Change the formula field so it would not reference any fields. I changed it to "test". Save it.
Then change it to what was initially required.

Comment: This worked for me