# Salesforce Encryption Enabled With Errors

Tags: formula, error, platform-encryption, shield-encryption, shield

I am trying to encrypt field Lead.Name but it fails due to:

```
Encryption can't be enabled for fields referenced in the custom formula fields: Lead.Data Quality Description.
```

I checked this formula field and all functions are allowed as listed here: [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.security_pe_formulas.htm&type=5#security_pe_formulas)
This is the definition of the text formula field:

```
IF(
    Data_Quality_Score__c = 100,
    "All Lead Details Captured", 
    "Missing: " & 
        IF( 
            ISNULL(FirstName),
            "First Name, ",
            ""
        )
    & "" & 
        IF(
            ISNULL(LastName),
            "Last Name, ",
            ""
        )
    & "" &
        IF(
            ISNULL(Company),
            "Company, ",
            ""
        )
    & "" &
        IF( 
            ISNULL(Phone),
            "Phone, ",
            ""
        )
    & "" &
        IF(
            ISPICKVAL(Salutation, ""),
            "Salutation, ",
            ""
        )
    & "" &
        IF(
            ISPICKVAL(Rating, ""),
            "Rating, ",
            ""
        )
    & "" &
        IF(
            ISNULL(City),
            "Complete Address, ",
            ""
        )
    & "" &
        IF(
            ISNULL(Email),
            "Email",
            ""
        )
)
```

Comment: The `=` operator is not in the list. Have you tried removing it?

Comment: Can you remove the field from the formula and then encrypt the field? After this, I believe you should be able to use it back in the formula. Recommend reviewing https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.security_pe_deterministic_considerations.htm&type=5

Comment: N.B. you can replace all the `""` with `NULL` and the concatenation works as expected; I agree with Swetha -- I had [similar issue](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/287719/change-a-formula-field-and-get-data-uniqueness-violation-the-proposed-data-cha/287720#287720) and had to encrypt first, then create the formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So [manjit5190](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/346475/salesforce-encryption-enabled-with-errors#comment507901_346475) was right. Using the `=` operator was the issue. The referenced field *Data_Quality_Score__c* used in the formula has been encrypted as well and therefore the problem using the `=` sign. Unfortunately, I did not find a workaround for this, so this Lead.Name field won't be encrypted.